# unit tests in Django - How to call a post function of a class based view

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-class-based-views

How to send form data to a post function from a unit test function?

Comment: Not without seeing some code.

Comment: try reading the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#overview-and-a-quick-example

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
request = self.client.post("/some/url/", post_date, follow=True)
```

Follow the documentation in djangoproject its clean and green